# Oracle 10g Cursor Error

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle10g

I am intermittently getting this error:

```
 ERROR: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

in my VB.Net console application.  The application works fine on my local machine but gets thrown in our production server.  Does anyone know of any logs or query on the Oracle10g application that can tell me what application, or process, is using up all the cursors or anyway to determining why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be closing them properly. It's also possible that you are not causing the problem, someone else is. You can query open cursors using...

```
select o.sid, osuser, count(*) num_curs
from v$open_cursor o, v$session s
where o.sid=s.sid
group by o.sid, osuser
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Is there anyway you know of that can let me check this retroactively?  These errors occur at night and I just get the error logs when I get in.

Comment: No, I don't believe that history is kept. You could schedule it with a DBMS_JOB I suppose or write a script that runs on a PC every n minutes and writes the output to a log file.